# Store a for in loop in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, xcode6

I have a `for in` loop that scans through an array and gives back three different values. For each value a different `preformSegueWithIdentifier` is performed. A question is answered in the new view and after answering the question the view takes you back to the original view. But, the `for in` loop runs again from the beginning, redirecting me every time to the same view and answering the same question instead of advancing.

So I want to store the array and control where I left it in order to prevent the loop from repeating itself.

I'm kind of new to Swift so any help would be very much appreciated. Cheers!

Here is the loop:

```
   if let data = response.responseObject as? NSData {
            let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("response: \(str)") //prints the HTML of the page
            let json = JSON(data: data)
            let name = json["company"]["name"].stringValue
            let user = json["fields"]["user"]
            let extra = json["fields"]["custom"]
            for (i: String,custom: JSON)in extra {
                let type = custom["type"]
                let Qs = custom["displayName"]

                if type == "text"{
                    performSegueWithIdentifier(Text, sender: self)
                }

                if type == "multi"{
                    performSegueWithIdentifier(Multiple, sender: self)
                }
                if type == "ord"{
                    performSegueWithIdentifier(Ordinal, sender: self)
                }




            }
```

The array is taken from a json:

```
 global.token = defaults.stringForKey("MyKey")!
        var request = HTTPTask()
        request.requestSerializer = HTTPRequestSerializer()
        request.requestSerializer.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + global.token
        global.QRId =    global.url.substringFromIndex(advance(global.url.startIndex,31)) //retrieves the ID from the URL
        request.GET("url" , parameters: nil, completionHandler: {(response: HTTPResponse) -> Void in
            if let err = response.error {
                println("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                return //also notify app of failure as needed
            }
             if let data = response.responseObject as? NSData {
            let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("response: \(str)") //prints the HTML of the page
            let json = JSON(data: data)
            let name = json["company"]["name"].stringValue
            let user = json["fields"]["user"]
            let extra = json["fields"]["custom"]
```

And the json format is the following:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Test Relay #1",
    "anonymous": false,
    "fields": {
        "user": [
            "name",
            "email",
            "dateofbirth"
        ],
        "custom": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "displayName": "What did you like about our service today?"
            },
            {
                "type": "multi",
                "choices": [
                    "Red",
                    " Green",
                    " Blue",
                    " Orange"
                ],
                "displayName": "Which of these do you like the most?"
            },
            {
                "type": "ordinal",
                "choices": {
                    "max": "10",
                    "min": "1"
                },
                "displayName": "How would you rate us on a scale of 1-10?"
            }
        ]
    },
    "created_at": "2015-08-10 13:23:45",
    "updated_at": "2015-08-10 13:23:45",
    "company": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test Company",
        "address": "5 Test Place",
        "postcode": "TE57 1AB",
        "phonenumber": "0800001066",
        "countrycode": null,
        "created_at": "2015-08-10 12:17:15",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-10 12:17:15"
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a for in, you could for loop through the json custom array with  var i = 0 and < extra.count. Then you can save the index position you are at in nsuserdefaults or a global var and start off where you left off by checking the saved value.

Comment: thanks, but that only solves half of the problem, I would still be calling the whole class again, and therefore calling all the json again which is what im trying to avoid, I need to find a way to save the array, but your suggestion might  work once I find a way to save the array.

Comment: Where do you make your json call? if its in viewWillAppear it gets called when you segue back, but if it is in viewDidLoad it will not get recalled when you segue back.

Comment: wrote it in viewDidLoad(), so your solution might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you could implement it something like this, I did not check this in Xcode so beware of errors.

```
let extra = json["fields"]["custom"]
var i = 0

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if defaults.objectForKey("savedPosition") != nil {
    i = defaults.objectForKey("savedPosition") as! Int
}  

for i; i < extra.count; i++ {
    let type = extra[i]["type"]
    let Qs = extra[i]["displayName"]

    if type == "text"{
        defaults.setObject(i++, forKey: "savedPosition")
        performSegueWithIdentifier(Text, sender: self)
        break
    }

    if type == "multi"{
        defaults.setObject(i++, forKey: "savedPosition")
        performSegueWithIdentifier(Multiple, sender: self)
        break
    }

    if type == "ord"{
        defaults.setObject(i++, forKey: "savedPosition")
        performSegueWithIdentifier(Ordinal, sender: self)
        break
    }

    defaults.setObject(nil, forKey: "savedPosition")
}
```

Comment: to use the custom to identify the type you have to use   ´for (i: String,custom: JSON)in extra´

Comment: I'm using swiftyjson if that changes anything whatsoever

Comment: I edited the answer, I think you can do it like this extra[i]["type"]

Comment: all the performSegueWithIdentifier are executing at the same time, tired adding a return statement, but it didn't work and I tried making 'i' a global variable, i case th 'i=0' was messing up the code but that didn't work either

Comment: Try a break instead of return.